# Python 3.12 problem - captured string through input() could not be passed to and dir()

Tags: python

This code checks imported modules and gets the user option to recheck imported modules and also let coder to find imported module related details and read doc string.

```
import sys, os


def is_imported():
    check_name = input("enter module name: ")
    if check_name in sys.modules:
        sys.stdout.write("Module name entered is already imported"+": " + "True")
    else:
        sys.stdout.write("Module name entered is not imported"+": " + "False")
        
    check_functions_in_imported_module = input("\ndo you want to check all functions available in this imported module, press y/n : ")
```

below code block relates to problem statement

```
    if check_functions_in_imported_module == "y":
        l = dir(check_name)  ##Cannot pass right captured input to create list.
        print(l)
        for i in range(0,len(l)):
            print (l[i], end='\n')
        check_wish_to_read_doc_for_module = input("\ndo you want to read doc related to impoted module, press y/n : ")
        if check_wish_to_read_doc_for_module == "y":
            sys.stdout.write(check_name.__doc__)
        else:
            pass
        
        
        check_wish_to_read_doc_for_fucntions =  input("\ndo you want to check a specific function details in this imported module, mention function name : ")
        if check_wish_to_read_doc_for_fucntions:
            newstring = check_name + '.' + check_wish_to_read_doc_for_fucntions
            la = dir(newstring)
            for j in range(0, len(la)):
                print(la[j], end='\n')
                
            readdocstring = newstring + "." + "__doc__"
            sys.stdout.write(readdocstring)
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
            

is_imported()


while 1:
    check_wish = input("\n\ndo you want to continue checking other imprted modules, press y/n ?: ")
    if check_wish == "y":
        is_imported()
    else :
        print("\nhappy to help when you come back again")
        break
```

I cannot pass captured `input()` into `dir()` to list down all inside imported module.
By default, it prints something that does not relate to all functions/docs available inside a module name that is captured through input().

Check comment section in this code, that is problem area

Comment: Please post what module is giving you the problem, what is being printed and what you expect to be printed. You haven't provided enough information to reproduce the problem. Have your tried passing a hardcoded module name inst qd of the input and check of this reproduces the problem? If so, the input is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: You're running dir() on a plain string, not a module/variable. Compare the output of just `dir("example")`

Comment: Note that `dir()` is explicitly documented as a facility for interactive human exploration; it's not designed for metaprogramming.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locals()[name]` to get the actual variable from its string name.

```
import math
modulename = 'math'

dir(modulename) # gives dir() of a string object

dir(locals()[modulename]) # gives dir() of the math module object
```